# Storing CollectionProperty for UIList in Addon Preferences or elsewhere?

Tags: python, interface

My add-on has a panel where a UIList is drawn.

```
row.template_list("MY_UL_List", "The_List", scene,
                          "my_list", scene, "list_index")
```

MY_UL_List is a UIList class containing the draw_items() function and my_list is the CollectionProperty (PropertyGroup class) with various StringProperties.

```
bpy.types.Scene.my_list = CollectionProperty(type = ListItem)
```

ListItem class looks like this:

```
class ListItem(PropertyGroup):
    """Group of properties representing an item in the list."""

    name: StringProperty(
           name="Name",
           description="A name for this item",
           default="Untitled")

    random_prop: StringProperty(
           name="Any other property you want",
           description="",
           default="")
```

The user can add items to my_list with:

```
bpy.context.scene.my_list.add()
```

I would like blender to store the items that are added to the list and not "empty the list" when restarting or opening a new blend file.

I have been playing around with bpy.types.AddonPreferences and am able to store items from my_list in an EnumProperty inside the AddonPreferences class. However, I don't know if it's possible to populate the my_list CollectionProperty (and therefore my UIList in my panel) with items saved in Addon Preferences.

Comment: Hello, could you post the code for `ListItem` too ? or a stripped down version. Custom properties should be saved when quitting / reloading Blender.

Comment: Oh, you mean between different blend files ? The only way AFAIK is indeed to store the properties in the addon preferences, not on the current scene. Code wise it's the same thing, so if it works with your scene you just have to point your UI list to a collection property stored in your addon prefs.

Comment: "you just have to point your UI list to a collection property stored in your addon prefs" - I am not sure how that works. I was under the impression that CollectionProperty should point to the PropertyGroup class (added code in my original question). Could you fill me in on how to add CollectionProperty under addon preferences class and then point UIList to that? Thanks.

Comment: Presets are stored external to the blend file as an option.

Comment: Here's an example in one of my addons where I used both `PointerProperty` and `CollectionProperty` https://github.com/Gorgious56/asset_browser_utilities/blob/153081aeea3a215f2719a9fbcc614fed76e3b74e/core/preferences/ui.py#L7-L12 and FWIW the relevant Property Group (don't try to understand what it does, I have long forgotten) https://github.com/Gorgious56/asset_browser_utilities/blob/153081aeea3a215f2719a9fbcc614fed76e3b74e/core/cache/prop.py#L27

Comment: to get your addon preferences `prefs = bpy.context.preferences.addons["your_addon_name"].preferences` then simply `layout.prop(prefs, "my_list")` - or a little bit more work in case of a UI list but this should get you started

Comment: Do note that I'm almost certain this use of the addon preferences to store data between blender sessions is not really intended by the developpers and can lead to unforeseen behaviour. I've never witnessed any odd things myself but I wouldn't be surprised if it made Blender crash a little bit more often

Comment: Aha thanks. Also, an error I was making was neglecting to check which order my classes were being registered. I was getting an error about the CollectionProperty inside AddonPreferences not being found because the class that it was referring to (type=SomeClass) was being registered after the Panel class.

Comment: So I can modify the CollectionProperty in my AddonPreferences within the scope of the AddonPreferences class. However, I'm not sure if it's possible to do it from outside, e.g. from another bpy.types.Panel class. I'm getting an error type object SomeAddonPrefs has no attribute 'col_prop', when trying to do SomeAddonPrefs.col_prop.add(). But self.col_prop.add() within AddonPreferences does work.

Comment: well I went for a walk and remembered that outside AddonPrefs class I can just use item = bpy.context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences.col_prop.add()